# How to get the data from table where column equals NULL

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE Reports (
         _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,member_id INTEGER, 
      is_conf BOOLEAN,
         name TEXT, 
      started INTEGER,

     finished INTEGER,
    description TEXT, 
       obj_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     FOREIGN KEY (obj_id) REFERENCES Objects (_id));
```

I want to get data where `member_id = NULL`.
But the query:

```
String sql = "SELECT _id, name FROM Reports WHERE member_id = NULL";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

doesn't work.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work is that *nothing* "equals" `NULL` - not even `NULL`!. Thus the `=` (equality) operator will never succeeded for a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use this:

```
String sql = "SELECT _id, name FROM Reports WHERE member_id IS NULL";
```

Comment: `.. member_id ISNULL` is an alternate valid syntax.

Comment: Не за что! Also I don't believe `ISNULL` works in SQLite... does it?

Answer (score 0):

Use IFNULL as described in the documentations at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull

Comment: `IFNULL` is different. It can't be used as a predicate, but it can "translate" a `NULL` value to something else.